# Open a Windows app programmatically, when it was installed with MSIX Application Packager

Tags: windows, visual-studio, packaging, sideloading, msix

I have packaged my windows App using a Visual Studio MSIX Packaging Project: This is a sideloading app, using a certificate, not a Microsoft Store App.
This is fine - I get automatic updates, and users can install the package without admin rights.

I want to be able to open this app from another app.
Before this was easy - just call Process.Start with the app path: "C:\Program Files\MyCompany\MyApp.exe"

However the Executable for an MSIX installed app is hidden I suspect its in "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps" but this folder is restricted and I can't get access even with admin permissions

There appears to be some data about the installation in C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\Packages{myappguid} - but no executable files are available here.

So my question is simple: How can I launch an app from another program, when the app was installed using the MSIX application packager?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This turned out to be fairly simple.

Edit your Package.appmanifest and add the following in the Application element

```xml
<Extensions>
  <uap5:Extension Category="windows.appExecutionAlias">
    <uap5:AppExecutionAlias>
      <uap5:ExecutionAlias Alias="MyApp.exe"/>
    </uap5:AppExecutionAlias> 
  </uap5:Extension>
</Extensions>
```

And ensure this namespace is referenced at the top of the manifest file `xmlns:uap5="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10/5"`
and is in the ignorable namespaces too.

Rebuild and re-install the MSIX.

Test at a new command-prompt - just type MyApp.exe - it should open the app.

Now the second program can execute `Process.Start("MyApp.exe")` and it works.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/uapmanifestschema/element-uap5-extension